# Hypothesis to conclusion using tautologies

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm teaching myself Analysis, using Steven Lay's Analysis, With an Introduction to Proof.

I need to establish a conclusion given a hypothesis, using a list of tautologies, I've attached an image below of the given tautologies.

[image]

Hypothesis: $ r,\sim t,(r \land s) \implies t  $

Conclusion: $ \sim s $

I first used (c) the contrapositive,

$ \sim t \implies ( \sim r \lor \sim s ) $

I'm well aware that since $ \sim t $ is True, as stated in the hypothesis, then we can eliminate it and get to $ ( \sim r \lor \sim s ) $ but I'm stuck there and I'm not understanding also what they're doing in the solutions provided.

The solution provided by the book states the following steps:

1. $ \sim t \implies ( \sim r \lor \sim s ) $  contrapositive of
   hypothesis 3.12(c)
2. $ \sim r \lor \sim s $  by 3.12(h)
3. $ \sim s $  by 3.12(j)

I'm not understanding how he went from 1 to 2 using h, and 2 to 3 using j, some assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: The author is ommiting some details. Are you familiar with the notions of [formal consequence/entailment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence#Syntactic_consequence), [material conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional), and the [deduction theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, by hypothesis you can take the contraposition 
$$\neg t\Rightarrow (\neg r\vee \neg s).$$
Second, $\neg t$ holds by hypothesis and so by modus ponens
$$\neg r \vee \neg s.$$
Third, $r$ by hypothesis and so
$$r \wedge (\neg r\vee \neg s)$$
which is by the law of absorption logically equivalent to $\neg s$. Done.

Comment: I wasn't seeing it, but then it clicked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To see how to go from step 1 to step 2, let $p=\sim t$ and $q=(\sim r\vee\sim s)$. To see step 2 to step 3, let $p = \sim r$ and $q = \sim s$, and recall that $p = \sim\sim p$.